# About discord.js V13 start all Intents

Tags: javascript

The thing is like this, I try to upgrade my original robot to V13
, So I decided to rewrite the bot.

I don’t know how to get all Intents at once
I tried Intents.all but it didn't work
this is my code

```js
const { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
const cofing = require("./cofig.json");

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("================");
    console.log("|i am ready|");
    console.log("================");
});

  client.on('message', async message => {
 if(message.content === 'test'){
     console.log("test")
 } 
});
client.login(cofing.token);
```

If you could tell me how to write this, I would be very grateful

Comment: Do you have a typo at `3:26`? It looks like you mean `config.json` instead of `cofig.json`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First of all:**
There is a small error in your message event (`client.on('message', ... )`), it's no longer 'message', but 'messageCreate' in v13, so keep in mind u have to update that.

**About the intents:**
If you would like to use all intents (which I don't recommend), you can define all the intents in one intent via a **Bitfield**, you do this with the following code:

```js
const allIntents = new Intents(7796);
const client = new Client({ intents: allIntents });
```

**FYI:** First in the beginning of v13 there was a flag called `ALL` (Intents.FLAGS.ALL), but that was removed afterwards, so this is the alternative to it.

Answer (score 1):

`const {Client,intents,Collection, DiscordAPIError, Guild} = require("discord.js") const client = new Client ({intents:[7796]})`

The Intents: 32767 Is Not Working Anymore

Comment: I edited it in my answer, thank you for sharing this.