# Is there a way to add all intents to a Discord.js bot in v14?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to create a new client with all intents but nothing I have found online has solved the issue. Here is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: 7796 })
```

Comment: according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68866904/14950361) on another post, i think you may need to import `Intents`, and create the intent with it. `const allIntents = new Intents(7796);` then `const client = new Client({ intents: allIntents });`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
  intents: Object.keys(GatewayIntentBits).map((a)=>{
    return GatewayIntentBits[a]
  }),
});
```

The intents option is passed to the Client constructor as an object. The `GatewayIntentBits` object is imported from the discord.js module and contains a list of all available intents that can be used with the Discord API.

The `Object.keys()` method is used to get an `array` of all the keys in the `GatewayIntentBits` object. The map() method is then used to iterate over each key in the array and return the corresponding value from the `GatewayIntentBits` object.

In other words, this code is creating a new Discord client with all available intents enabled. This is necessary to receive certain events from the Discord API, such as message events etc...

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.