# Discord.js Error: TypeError: Intents is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

I was trying to get my Discord bot ported over to v14 from v9 after using the latter for far longer than supported. I ran into an issue with Intents and then found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68791091/about-discord-js-v13-start-all-intents/68866904#68866904) on stackoverflow. However, this solution created an error:

> PS C:\Users\MYUSNM\OneDrive\Desktop\Botto (v0.2)> node index.js
> C:\Users\MYUSNM\OneDrive\Desktop\Botto (v0.2)\index.js:8
> const allIntents = new Intents(7796);
> ^
>
> TypeError: Intents is not a constructor
> at Object. (C:\Users\yuxua\OneDrive\Desktop\MCWipeout (v0.2)\index.js:8:20)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
>
> Node.js v18.13.0

I've tried swapping locations of everything, it just ran into different errors, some saying the Intents wasn't declared yet (which makes sense) and some just straight up didn't work.

Here's the code snippet.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const ms = require('ms')
const moment = require('moment')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const { GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');
const { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const allIntents = new Intents(7796);
const client = new Client({ intents: allIntents });

const config = require('./storage/config.json')
client.commands = new Discord.Collection()

const Logs = require('./models/logs.js')
```

Comment: Are you certain you are using v13?

Comment: my mistake. I meant v14. Must've clicked on the wrong button. I'll change it in the original post now.

Comment: Well the solution you linked to is outdated and no longer works for v14. Have you tried exploring solutions in the [up-to-date official guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/main-file.html)?